# function inside ajax call respond is not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

I need to check language already Exist condition{ without page reload/load }, so that i called ajax at End of my function.

I have a doubt, that can i call function inside ajax call to get a responce before **return true** statement execute????

**my code :**

```
function languageValid(){
    if( field1 === '' ){
        return false;
    }
    if( field2 === '' ){
        return false;
    }
    if( field3 === '' ){
        return false;
    }
    // e.g : ajax call
    $.post(sitePath+"candidate/index/langues-update",{},function(responce){
        // responce as  '0' or '1'
        exist   =   $.trim(responce);
        if(exist){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

 calling function
 languageValid();
```

function does not wait for ajax call respond,
it will execute **return true** before ajax call
pls share your suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your bloc below returns a value from the $.post() function.

```
 if(exist){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

If you want to get the response, you can try:

```
    function languageValid(){ .....
    var result = $.post('url',{},function(responce){}).responseText;

    exist   =   $.trim(result);
     if(exist){
            return false;
    }else{
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i got "result" as always NULL did u try above code in Your project?